# How to fix "error: cannot find symbol import io.vertx.core.json" Vertx

Tags: java, openjdk, rpc

I followed these steps to install Vert.x on my machine.

- Intall OpenJDK : `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`
- Test java installation: `java -version` which is giving me 3 outputs:

  1. `openjdk version "1.8.0_242"`
  2. `OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-8u242-b08-0ubuntu3~18.04-b08)`
  3. `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b08, mixed mode)`
- Download latest version of Vert.x at https://vertx.io/
- Untar the downloaded file: `tar xzvf vert.x-3.8.5-full.tar.gz`
- Make vertx executable: `chmod +x vertx/bin/vertx`
- Go in the bin folder: `cd vertx/bin`
- Test Vert.x version: `./vertx version` which is giving me 3.8.5 as output

I then created a .java file with the following code in it:

```
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.eventbus.EventBus;

public class Producteur extends AbstractVerticle 
{
    public void start() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("> Launching...");

        final EventBus eb = vertx.eventBus();

        vertx.setPeriodic(1000, v -> {

            eb.send("canal-ptp", "Hello", reply -> {

                if(reply.succeeded())
                    System.out.println("> Response received : " + reply.result().body());
                else
                    System.out.println("> No response!");
            });
        });
    }
}
```

This code is working fine when launch with the following command is a terminal:

```
./vertx run Producteur.java --cluster
```

But when I add the following import at the beginning of the java file:

```
import io.vertx.core.json;
```

I get the following error:

[image: error: cannot find symbol import io.vertx.core.json]

What am I missing? I don't get why the other imports are fine, but this one isn't. In the end, I'd like to replace the `"Hello"` string with a json object.

Please note that I'm a complete noob with ubuntu/java/vertx overall. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import io.vertx.core.json;
```

is not a module you can import.

```
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
```

is.